# Is there known PlayStation Network Status page?

Tags: psn, ps3

Right now my PS3 is having difficulties signing in to the PlayStation Network.  Has anyone found an official status page for the PSN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google lead me to this post which is concise. I'll quote it here for others.

> Servers are not down, atleast not on my end. Check your internet connection settings on PS3.
>
> For future reference, Support page
>   gets an update if network is down.
>
> Also, Playstation's Twitter account
>   also gets an update alongside
>   Playstation Blog.
>
> EDIT: For a more visual answer, look
>   at the bar on top right.
>   PlayStation®Network  On

Ref: http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showpost.php?p=25919934&postcount=2

So in short, hit up this page, and check the top right hand corner,  http://uk.playstation.com/psn/

Comment: Looks like the UK PSN page has the little green status icon, but the US site doesn't.

Comment: Rather than having a standing status page, the US PSN posts a forum post when there is maintenance.

Comment: I'll add a link to this here also, http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-13169518 , as the outage seems to be linked to a hack

Comment: Hack or no hack, I called my bank yesterday and had them issue me a new credit card all the same.